# How to save file paths to my postgreSQL database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

I am trying to save an image I uploaded from an html form field as a binary file to a postgresql database. I found a code example that does this with Java. But I haven't been able to make any progress on how to do it with Javascript. I am not using any js framework. I would be glad if you can assist.

The following is the java code of what I am trying to do. I need to do this using javascript, taking it from the html form.

```
JavaPostgreSqlWriteImage.java
package com.zetcode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaPostgreSqlWriteImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb";
        String user = "user12";
        String password = "34klq*";

        String query = "INSERT INTO images(data) VALUES(?)";
        
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)) {

            File img = new File("src/main/resources/sid.jpg");

            try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(img)) {

                pst.setBinaryStream(1, fin, (int) img.length());
                pst.executeUpdate();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaPostgreSqlWriteImage.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(JavaPostgreSqlWriteImage.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically you don't connect a browser directly to a database, instead you should use server-side code.

Comment: I need to link the image uploaded from the html field to the web service and then save it to the database, but I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's definitely not a task to do in a browser. Just think about it, you should expose the username and password, your control to queries would be minimal, a user could execute any query the role of the user has been granted.